# Check a specific set of metacharacters in Java \$ or \,

Tags: java, regex

I need to check a specific set of the special characters: `\$` or `\,`  is present in String.
   Example;

```
  1) \\ghg$ : invalid
  2) \\ghg\\$ : valid
  3) ghg$ : invalid
  4) \\ghg\\,$ : invalid. Here $ is not escaped 
  5) ghg\\,\\$ : valid
```

Below is the code,

```
private static void regexValidation(String text, String pattern) {
        System.out.println(text + " and pattern " + pattern + " used" + ":" + text.matches(pattern) + " with pattern "
                + Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text).matches() + " with find "
                + Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text).find());
    }
```

The pattern used was `pattern = ".*\\$.*";` which didnt give the expected result. Was using `".*\\B\\$\\B.*"` but this also fails in the 4th case. Is there a way in java we can do filter the special character set?

Comment: Maybe a simple `text.matches(".*([\\\\$]).*")` does the trick? Since both `\` and `$` are single characters, you can put them in a range like `[abc]` will match a, b or c.

Comment: "special characters: `\$` or `\,` is present" -> find `\\[$,]`  (not sure why example 4 is invalid, definitively a `\,` is present)

Comment: Are your examples *string literals* (did you copy them from inside `"..."` in your code?) or *literal strings*? I think that you may use `matches("(?s)[^$,]*(?:\\\\.[^$,]*)*(?:\\\\[$,][^$,]*(?:\\\\.[^$,]*)*)+")` to validate.

Answer (score 0):

seems your requirement is not very clear:

according to your `\$ or \,`, then `\\ghg\\,$` should match, for it contain the `\\,`, which match `\,`

so if your requirement is: match `\$` or `\,`, then

- regex: `((\\\$)|(\\,))`
- match result (show in https://regexr.com):

  - [image]

if you just want to test match or not, can use:

- regex: `(((?<=\\)\$)|(\\,))`
- result:

  - [image]

Comment: `\\ghg\\,$` is invalid because `,` is escaped but `$` is not.

Comment: but you said: \$ or \,, so match any one of this two, is match, so \\ghg\\,$ match the one \, means match, means valid, right ?

Comment: i have listed examples